# Determine the value of theta in given equation.

Tags: trigonometry

Given if $\sin2\theta$ = $2\sin\theta$, what would be the value of $\theta(\mathrm{principal})$. I asked my elder and he used $\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$, I don't understand this now (nor do I want to), is there any other method? I am not that specialised in this field. Please keep it the minimal.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Nor do you want to? What type of a class is this for?

Comment: @robjohn I am in 9th standard and this is an objective question, when i asked my teacher he said substitute the options and check.

Comment: So if I understand, this is a multiple choice question? That (and the choices) would be useful information to give so that someone might present a helpful answer. Is this a trigonometry class or a geometry class?

Comment: @robjohn trignometry class

Comment: I am surprised that a trig textbook does not cover sum of angle and double angle formulas. Since I can't think of a non-trigonometric way to solve this problem, I would be left with substituting in the options given you.

Comment: @robjohn that's exactly what my teacher said, but know i understand sum of angle and double angle formula (wikipedia). Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ (and this is true no matter what number $\theta$ is) and that $\sin(2\theta)=\sin\theta$ (and this is true only for the particular numbers you're seeking), then you have
$$
2\sin\theta\cos\theta = 2\sin\theta.
$$
You can divide by sides by $2\sin\theta$ **unless** $\sin\theta=0$.  Then you get
$$
\cos\theta = 1.
$$
So either $\sin\theta=0$ or $\cos\theta=1$.  But additionally, when $\cos\theta=1$ then in every case, $\sin\theta=0$, so it's redundant to add $\sin\theta=0$.

So you just need to find values of $\theta$ for which $\cos\theta=1$.